# what's wrong with this PHP function

Tags: php

I am trying to extract a value from an array if it exists in the array but i always get null even when I know the value does exist

this works

```
$data['key']
```

this doesn't work. getVal1 returns null

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO test (text, date) VALUES ('".getVal1('key',$data)."', NOW())";


function getVal1($name,$d){
        if ($d !=null && in_array($name, $d) ) {
            return $d[$name];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is there something wrong in my `getVal1()` function?

Comment: First `$d !=null` should be `!is_null($d)`. And `in_array($name, $d)` should be `isset($d[$name])`.

Comment: It should be `$d !== null`, if anything. One does not need an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: In fact you could just do `isset` since it returns false on null as well.

Comment: Are you confusing keys with values? `in_array()` is searching for a value; but you're return assumes that it's a key

Comment: Please read what [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) actually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `in_array` searches for array values, yet you are passing it an array key.

You code can be simplified with isset and ternary if:

```
function getVal1($name,$d){
    return isset($d[$name])?$d[$name]:null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
if (isset($d[$name]))
    return $d[$name];
else
    return null;
```